# To Neo4j or to not? If yes, to what extent?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, neo4j

My Rails app relies on match making algorithms, for which I found Neo4j DB to be a great candidate. One issue is that I need to switch to JRuby in order to integrate Neo4j. Another gem called Neography doesn't need JRuby, but doesn't cover all the features of Neo4j. I'm not that happy switching to Java and JBoss.

Should I rely only on Neo4j, or should I have SQL (mySql or PostGRE) to store all my data and use Neo4G just for match making?

If yes to the second, how hard would it be to integrate both databases, how hard would it be to use Neo4j only for the match making, and what should I take into consideration?

Another issue is keeping both DBs synchronized.

Comment: Will probably need to know a bit more about your models. For example, I don't see why you would move your users model which has email, password, etc into neo4G.

Comment: Definitely I wouldn't. But there is still the question of using only Neo4G, which means no DB sync headaches.

Answer (score 1):

Neography supports all features of Neo4j that you would need.

There is no need to go with jruby and neo4j.rb if you don't want to.

Shouldn't be too hard to synchronize the two db's. Just write consistently to both.

In Neo4j you probably just want to keep the data needed for the matchmaking queries.

Comment: Thanks. This sounds like what I envisioned.

Comment: Neography is not a drop-in replacement for ActiveRecord the way Neo4j.rb is, so Michael's statement is only true if you aren't looking to use Neo4j for anything other than matching. If you want to take advantage of your Rails models, Neo4j.rb is what you'll need. JRuby isn't that bad! Torquebox is great for Rails app hosting.